# Can I send non-IP packets using Winsock?

Tags: sockets, networking, winsock, pppoe

I'm trying to create a small PPPoE Access Concentrator to learn the inner workings of PPPoE.
This requires me to send non-IP packets, I need to be able to set the ETHER_TYPE and eventualy the destination mac fields in the ethernet frame header, but as far as I can tell, raw WinSock sockets give me the ability to supply my own IP header, but not the ethernet header.

Is this true? And if so, is there any way of circumventing this?

I am well aware of WinPcap, and will use it ONLY as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are correct.  Winsock will allow a raw IP socket but does not allow you to get beneath layer 3 and send non-IP packets.  For this I believe you would need to pursue the WinPcap / TDI option .  More [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About TDI, I would need a driver to gain access to it, since it is only available in kernel mode, correct?